# CALL multiple procedures with python

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have a linux server and I would like to run a python script every day to run mysql procedures but I do not know how to run multiple procedures and put a condition if there is an error that it sends me an email with the description of the error. Here is my script with only one procedure:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","bddname" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("CALL proc_commande_clts_detail7();")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()
print "Database version : %s " % data

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [callproc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html) method to execute MySQL procedures

```
for proc_name in proc_name_list:
    try:
        result_args = cursor.callproc(proc_name, args=())
    except Exception as e:
        send_mail(str(e))
```

If you want to call multiple procedures, you can put callproc in some kind of loop and use try...catch for error handling.

Comment: I do not see how the callproc function is used to execute multiple procedures. Do you have an example? Thank you

Comment: proc_name_list is array ?

Comment: yeah...anything which is iterable. list, set, dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping them in try/except block and trigger email in except block?
Scheduling can be done through cron job.

```
import traceback

try:
    cursor.execute("CALL proc_commande_clts_detail7();")
catch Exception as e:
    email_msg = traceback.format_exc()
    #send email logic
```